# csv file UTF-8 (with BOM) to ANSI / Windows-1251

Tags: windows, batch-file, utf-8, vbscript, codepages

I'm looking to create a batch file / macro to remove the first line of an auto generated UTF-8 CSV and convert it to Windows code page 1251 ("ANSI").
I've been looking all over the internet and tried a lot of things, but just can't find one that works...

Removing the first line is simple enough

```
@echo off
set "csv=test.csv"
more +1 "%csv%" >"%csv%.new"
move /y "%csv%.new" "export\%csv%" >nul
```

after that I'm lost, Ive tried using the TYPE set from DOS

```
cmd /a /c TYPE test.csv > ansi.csv
```

and many variations on this, but it either returns an empty CP1251 file or just another UTF file.

I've tried using vbs but this returned another UTF-8 file but now without BOM

```
Option Explicit

Private Const adReadAll = -1
Private Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
Private Const adTypeText = 2
Private Const adWriteChar = 0

Private Sub UTF8toANSI(ByVal UTF8FName, ByVal ANSIFName)
    Dim strText

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .LoadFromFile UTF8FName
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        strText = .ReadText(adReadAll)
        .Position = 0
        .SetEOS
        .Charset = "_autodetect" 'Use current ANSI codepage.
        .WriteText strText, adWriteChar
        .SaveToFile ANSIFName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

UTF8toANSI "UTF8-wBOM.txt", "ANSI1.txt"
UTF8toANSI "UTF8-noBOM.txt", "ANSI2.txt"
MsgBox "Complete!", vbOKOnly, WScript.ScriptName
```

EDIT1: 
tried converting to iso-8859-1 instead of cp1251 using vbs

```
Option Explicit

Private Const adReadAll = -1
Private Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
Private Const adTypeText = 2
Private Const adWriteChar = 0

Private Sub UTF8toANSI(ByVal UTF8FName, ByVal ANSIFName)
  Dim strText

  With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .LoadFromFile UTF8FName
    .Type = adTypeText
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    strText = .ReadText(adReadAll)
    .Position = 0
    .SetEOS
    .Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    .WriteText strText, adWriteChar
    .SaveToFile ANSIFName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
  End With
End Sub

UTF8toANSI WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)
```

This however also did not work.

EDIT 2:
I found a way to convert the files from UTF to ANSI using stringconverter.exe 
(downloaded from http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/tools.htm )

```
Setlocal
Set _source=C:\Users\lloyd.EVD\delFirstBat\import
Set _dest=C:\Users\lloyd.EVD\delFirstBat\export
For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ('dir /b /a-d "%_source%\*.CSV"') Do stringconverter "%_source%\%%~nxI" "%_dest%\%%~nxI" /ANSI
```

How ever now when I remove the first line of the file (either before or after, doesn't matter) it becomes a UTF-8 without BOM again.

So all I should need now is a script to del first row without changing the charset.

Comment: The name "ANSI", though it's commonly used, is inaccurate. It probably refers to one of the 8-bit code pages used on Microsoft Windows, perhaps Windows-1252. If you're converting UTF-8 to Windows-1252, you could run into characters that can't be converted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: Yes we need the files to be in W-1251. We already filled out system in such a way these non-convertible characters should not be used. fact remains, the system generates a utf-8 .csv and the system we wish to import it in requires an ANSI .csv without headers

Comment: You should update the question to specify Windows-1251.

Comment: If it's just a one-off, move the file to a Unix system and do `sed 1d file | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1251 >newfile` ... if you have a local system you can `ssh` to, you don't even need to store the file there physically; `plink remote 'sed 1d | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1251' <original.csv >fixed.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next *VBScript* could help: procedure `UTF8toANSI` converts a `UTF-8` encoded text file to another encoding.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const adReadAll = -1
Private Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
Private Const adTypeText = 2
Private Const adWriteChar = 0

Private Sub UTF8toANSI(ByVal UTF8FName, ByVal ANSIFName, ByVal ANSICharSet)
  Dim strText

  With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = adTypeText

    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile UTF8FName
    strText = .ReadText(adReadAll)
    .Close

    .Charset = ANSICharSet
    .Open
    .WriteText strText, adWriteChar
    .SaveToFile ANSIFName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
  End With
End Sub

'UTF8toANSI WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)
UTF8toANSI "D:\test\SO\38835837utf8.csv", "D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1250.csv", "windows-1250"
UTF8toANSI "D:\test\SO\38835837utf8.csv", "D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1251.csv", "windows-1251"
UTF8toANSI "D:\test\SO\38835837utf8.csv", "D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1253.csv", "windows-1253"
```

For a list of the character set names that are known by a system, see the subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Charset` in the Windows Registry:

```
for /F "tokens=5* delims=\" %# in ('reg query HKCR\MIME\Database\Charset') do @echo "%#"
```

**Data** (`38835837utf8.csv` file):

```
1st Line    1250    852 čeština (Čechie)
2nd Line    1251    966 русский (Россия)
3rd Line    1253    737 ελληνικά (Ελλάδα)
```

**Output** shows that those characters that can't be converted to a particular character set are converted using [Character Decomposition Mapping](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html#Character%20Decomposition) (`č`=>`c`, `š`=>`s`, `Č`=>`C` etc.); if not applicable then those are all converted to `?` question mark (common replacement character):

```
==> chcp 1250
Active code page: 1250

==> type D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1250.csv
1st Line        1250    852     čeština (Čechie)
2nd Line        1251    966     ??????? (??????)
3rd Line        1253    737     ???????? (??????)

==> chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

==> type D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1251.csv
1st Line        1250    852     cestina (Cechie)
2nd Line        1251    966     русский (Россия)
3rd Line        1253    737     ???????? (??????)

==> chcp 1253
Active code page: 1253

==> type D:\test\SO\38835837ansi1253.csv
1st Line        1250    852     cestina (Cechie)
2nd Line        1251    966     ??????? (??????)
3rd Line        1253    737     ελληνικά (Ελλάδα)
```